# Not able to configure hashicorp-vault with Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, hashicorp-vault

I want to generate postgres credentials/tokens dynamically using hashicorp-vault. For that I am referring https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/databases/postgresql.html .

Here is the command to configure the plugin:

```
vault write database/config/my-postgresql-database \
    plugin_name=postgresql-database-plugin \
    allowed_roles="my-role" \
    connection_url="postgresql://{{username}}:{{password}}@localhost:5432/" \ 
    username="root" \
    password="root"
```

However following error is thrown

```
* error creating database object: error verifying connection: pq: SSL is not enabled on the server
```

Can you guys help me in resolving the error?

Note: Mine is dev server hence the SSL is not enabled. I don't know how to enable that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `?sslmode=disable` to your connection_url. For example -

`connection_url="postgresql://{{username}}:{{password}}@localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable`

You can read about more ssl configuration [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/postgresql.html#postgresql-examples)

But, even if you are running a development db you should consider using ssl.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out. Will go through the URL as well.

Comment: What if you want to run a production environment? How can you enable sslmode?